# rsync: listing only changed files/attributes

Tags: linux, rsync, synology, qnap

I am trying to achieve the following:

In order to check whether I correctly rsynced all data from my old NAS to my new, I am executing:

```
rsync --rltD -hvinu /path/to/old/NAS/ /path/to/new/NAS
```

Now: -n is getting me a dry-run, -i a list of changes and -u should skip all files newer on the new NAS (which I need because there are already updates on the new NAS - people are working with it already).

The above command is giving me a listing that contains this for several directories:

```
.d..t
```

which acc. to man-page means that no transfer will happen, but that attributes (i.e. the time) will be updated in the target.

Checking the affected directory, I can see that the directory in the target is NEWER than the one in the source.

So I'd

1. expect to not even see it in rsyncs output - since it should have been skipped,
2. there should not ever be an update of that timestamp.
   -u should take care of that.

Any rsync pro here who can explain? What am I not getting here?

btw.: This is an rsync implementation on a Qnap NAS (source) and Synology NAS (target).

UPDATE 1:

So it seems that --update only applies to files, not directories.
rsync is doing what it is supposed to do: compare size and last-modified timestamp and updating the timestamp in the destination to the one in the source (which is older).

I have not found an option to apply --update to directories - there is however --omit-dir-times that will ignore timestamps on directories.
Applying that option, will also result in newer directories in the source to be ignored. So an added file in the source will be synced to destination, but the corresponding change in its parent directory's time will not be synced. I cannot imagine this to be a  bug/flaw in rsync - I must be missing something here?